# Getting the recipe (conanfile.py) of a conan package?

Tags: conan

For some package P in my local cache, how do I get the recipe (conanfile.py) of package P?

For example, let's take a conan package called:

```
zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable
```

I can install this package into my local cache from conan-center like so:

```
$ conan install zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable --remote conan-center
```

How do I unpack the recipe (conanfile.py) of this zlib package into the current directory?

```
$ mkdir zlib
$ cd zlib
$ conan ??? zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable
         ^.... what goes here?
$ cat conanfile.py
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `conan get` command. It can be used like:

```
conan get zlib/1.2.8@conan/stable -r conan-center
```

This will print `conanfile` and you don't even need to `cat` it afterwards.
More details about `conan get` here: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/get.html

Comment: As a note, the ``get`` command works the same in the local cache without specifying the remote ``-r=conan-center``